# phpmyAdmin & SQL error INSERT INTO command

Tags: mysql, insert

I am attempting to insert 288 records into an empty table.  I get a variety or errors.:   (Abbreviated data as apparently it is too big to post)

```
insert into bbschdeft (tSchSeason, tSchWk, tSchDay, tSchDate, tSchGmTime, tSchVTFN, tSchHTFN, tSchTVNtwk, tSchVTAbrv, tSchVTC, tSchVTD, tSchHTAbrv, tSchHTC, tSchHTD, tSchLocation)
VALUES (
'2020', '1', 'Thu', '2020/09/10', '18:20', 'Houston Texans', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'NBC', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'Kansas City',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'FOX', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'Atlanta',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'CBS', 'CLE', 'A', 'N', 'BAL', 'A', 'N', 'Baltimore',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'New York Jets', 'Buffalo Bills', 'CBS', 'NYJ', 'A', 'E', 'BUF', 'A', 'E', 'Buffalo',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Carolina Panthers', 'CBS', 'LVR', 'A', 'W', 'CAR', 'N', 'S', 'Carolina',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Chicago Bears', 'Detroit Lions', 'FOX', 'CHI', 'N', 'N', 'DET', 'N', 'N', 'Detroit',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'CBS', 'IND', 'A', 'S', 'JAC', 'A', 'S', 'Jacksonville',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'FOX', 'GBP', 'N', 'N', 'MIN', 'N', 'N', 'Minnesota',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Miami Dolphins', 'New England Patriots', 'CBS', 'MIA', 'A', 'E', 'NEP', 'A', 'E', 'New England',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'Washington Redskins', 'FOX', 'PHI', 'N', 'E', 'WAS', 'N', 'E', 'Washington',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '14:05', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'CBS', 'LAC', 'A', 'W', 'CIN', 'A', 'N', 'Cincinnati',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '14:25', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'New Orleans Saints', 'FOX', 'TBB', 'N', 'S', 'NOS', 'N', 'S', 'New Orleans',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '14:25', 'Arizona Cardinals', 'San Francisco 49ers', 'FOX', 'ARI', 'N', 'W', 'SFF', 'N', 'W', 'San Francisco',
'2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '18:20', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'NBC', 'DAL', 'N', 'E', 'LAR', 'N', 'W', 'Los Angeles',
'2020', '1', 'Mon', '2020/09/14', '17:15', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'New York Giants', 'ESPN', 'PIT', 'A', 'N', 'NYG', 'N', 'E', 'New York',
'2020', '1', 'Mon', '2020/09/14', '20:10', 'Tennessee Titans', 'Denver Broncos', 'ESPN', 'TEN', 'A', 'S', 'DEN', 'A', 'W', 'Denver',
'2020', '2', 'Thu', '2020/09/17', '18:20', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'NFLN', 'CIN', 'A', 'N', 'CLE', 'A', 'N', 'Cleveland',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago Bears', 'CBS', 'NYG', 'N', 'E', 'CHI', 'N', 'N', 'Chicago',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'FOX', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'DAL', 'N', 'E', 'Dallas',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'FOX', 'DET', 'N', 'N', 'GBP', 'N', 'N', 'Green Bay',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'FOX', 'MIN', 'N', 'N', 'IND', 'A', 'S', 'Indianapolis',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Miami Dolphins', 'CBS', 'BUF', 'A', 'E', 'MIA', 'A', 'E', 'Miami',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'San Francisco 49ers', 'New York Jets', 'FOX', 'SFF', 'N', 'W', 'NYJ', 'A', 'E', 'New York',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'FOX', 'LAR', 'N', 'W', 'PHI', 'N', 'E', 'Philadelphia',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Denver Broncos', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'CBS', 'DEN', 'A', 'W', 'PIT', 'A', 'N', 'Pittsburgh',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'FOX', 'CAR', 'N', 'S', 'TBB', 'N', 'S', 'Tampa Bay',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '11:00', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Tennessee Titans', 'CBS', 'JAC', 'A', 'S', 'TEN', 'A', 'S', 'Tennessee',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '14:05', 'Washington Redskins', 'Arizona Cardinals', 'FOX', 'WAS', 'N', 'E', 'ARI', 'N', 'W', 'Arizona',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '14:25', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Houston Texans', 'CBS', 'BAL', 'A', 'N', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'Houston',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '14:25', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'CBS', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'LAC', 'A', 'W', 'Los Angeles',
'2020', '2', 'Sun', '2020/09/20', '18:20', 'New England Patriots', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'NBC', 'NEP', 'A', 'E', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'Seattle',
'2020', '2', 'Mon', '2020/09/21', '18:15', 'New Orleans Saints', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'ESPN', 'NOS', 'N', 'S', 'LVR', 'A', 'W', 'Las Vegas',
'2020', '3', 'Thu', '2020/09/24', '18:20', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'NFLN', 'MIA', 'A', 'E', 'JAC', 'A', 'S', 'Jacksonville',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Chicago Bears', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'FOX', 'CHI', 'N', 'N', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'Atlanta',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Buffalo Bills', 'FOX', 'LAR', 'N', 'W', 'BUF', 'A', 'E', 'Buffalo',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Washington Redskins', 'Cleveland Browns', 'FOX', 'WAS', 'N', 'E', 'CLE', 'A', 'N', 'Cleveland',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Tennessee Titans', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'CBS', 'TEN', 'A', 'S', 'MIN', 'N', 'N', 'Minnesota',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'New England Patriots', 'CBS', 'LVR', 'A', 'W', 'NEP', 'A', 'E', 'New England',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'San Francisco 49ers', 'New York Giants', 'FOX', 'SFF', 'N', 'W', 'NYG', 'N', 'E', 'New York',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'CBS', 'CIN', 'A', 'N', 'PHI', 'N', 'E', 'Philadelphia',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '11:00', 'Houston Texans', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'CBS', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'PIT', 'A', 'N', 'Pittsburgh',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '14:05', 'New York Jets', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'CBS', 'NYJ', 'A', 'E', 'IND', 'A', 'S', 'Indianapolis',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '14:05', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'CBS', 'CAR', 'N', 'S', 'LAC', 'A', 'W', 'Los Angeles',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '14:25', 'Detroit Lions', 'Arizona Cardinals', 'FOX', 'DET', 'N', 'N', 'ARI', 'N', 'W', 'Arizona',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '14:25', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Denver Broncos', 'FOX', 'TBB', 'N', 'S', 'DEN', 'A', 'W', 'Denver',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '14:25', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'FOX', 'DAL', 'N', 'E', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'Seattle',
'2020', '3', 'Sun', '2020/09/27', '18:20', 'Green Bay Packers', 'New Orleans Saints', 'NBC', 'GBP', 'N', 'N', 'NOS', 'N', 'S', 'New Orleans',
'2020', '3', 'Mon', '2020/09/28', '18:15', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'ESPN', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'BAL', 'A', 'N', 'Baltimore',
'2020', '4', 'Thu', '2020/10/01', '18:20', 'Denver Broncos', 'New York Jets', 'NFLN', 'DEN', 'A', 'W', 'NYJ', 'A', 'E', 'New York',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Arizona Cardinals', 'Carolina Panthers', 'FOX', 'ARI', 'N', 'W', 'CAR', 'N', 'S', 'Carolina',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Chicago Bears', 'CBS', 'IND', 'A', 'S', 'CHI', 'N', 'N', 'Chicago',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'CBS', 'JAC', 'A', 'S', 'CIN', 'A', 'N', 'Cincinnati',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'FOX', 'CLE', 'A', 'N', 'DAL', 'N', 'E', 'Dallas',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'New Orleans Saints', 'Detroit Lions', 'FOX', 'NOS', 'N', 'S', 'DET', 'N', 'N', 'Detroit',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'Houston Texans', 'FOX', 'MIN', 'N', 'N', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'Houston',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Miami Dolphins', 'FOX', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'MIA', 'A', 'E', 'Miami',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'CBS', 'LAC', 'A', 'W', 'TBB', 'N', 'S', 'Tampa',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'Tennessee Titans', 'CBS', 'PIT', 'A', 'N', 'TEN', 'A', 'S', 'Tennessee',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '11:00', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Washington Redskins', 'CBS', 'BAL', 'A', 'N', 'WAS', 'N', 'E', 'Washington',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '14:05', 'New York Giants', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'FOX', 'NYG', 'N', 'E', 'LAR', 'N', 'W', 'Los Angeles',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '14:25', 'New England Patriots', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'CBS', 'NEP', 'A', 'E', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'Kansas City',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '14:25', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'CBS', 'BUF', 'A', 'E', 'LVR', 'A', 'W', 'Las Vegas',
'2020', '4', 'Sun', '2020/10/04', '18:20', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'San Francisco 49ers', 'NBC', 'PHI', 'N', 'E', 'SFF', 'N', 'W', 'San Francisco',
'2020', '4', 'Mon', '2020/10/05', '18:15', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Green Bay Packers', 'ESPN', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'GBP', 'N', 'N', 'Green Bay',
```

> Here is a partial error list:
> Static analysis:
>
> 8520 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 9382)
> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 9492)

Comment: Your statement has syntax errors that we can't see. These are probably caused by your data containing un-escaped `'` characters.

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.5.1,  PHP 7.0.4, Windows 10 laptop, all has been working fine, Apache & MySQL on same laptop

Comment: If there is too much data to post here try posting to db-fiddle. Also as an answer below says you need to bracket every row on a multi line insert. It's impossible to say what other errors you may have since you haven't published your table definition but you may have problems with the invalid date format of you are trying to insert to a date field.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is you are missing a lot of Brackets.

you code must be like seen below, for every row you need to enclose them with Brackets ()

```
insert into bbschdeft (tSchSeason, tSchWk, tSchDay, tSchDate, tSchGmTime, tSchVTFN, tSchHTFN, tSchTVNtwk, tSchVTAbrv, tSchVTC, tSchVTD, tSchHTAbrv, tSchHTC, tSchHTD, tSchLocation)
VALUES (
'2020', '1', 'Thu', '2020/09/10', '18:20', 'Houston Texans', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'NBC', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'Kansas City'),
('2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'FOX', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'Atlanta'),
('2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'CBS', 'CLE', 'A', 'N', 'BAL', 'A', 'N', 'Baltimore'),
```

Comment: No joy. - insert into bbschdeft (tSchSeason, tSchWk, tSchDay, tSchDate, tSchGmTime, tSchVTFN, tSchHTFN, tSchTVNtwk, tSchVTAbrv, tSchVTC, tSchVTD, tSchHTAbrv, tSchHTC, tSchHTD, tSchLocation)
VALUES 
('2020', '1', 'Thu', '2020/09/10', '18:20', 'Houston Texans', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'NBC', 'HOU', 'A', 'S', 'KCC', 'A', 'W', 'Kansas City'),
('2020', '1', 'Sun', '2020/09/13', '11:00', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'FOX', 'SEA', 'N', 'W', 'ATL', 'N', 'S', 'Atlanta'),   etc.  Same 8500+ errors

Comment: All bracketed, no improvement.

Comment: Source data csv was in error got sections inserted until I found all the errors.  ALL GOOD NOW!   Thanks!

Comment: that happens to most of us